# Usando tipo double em c++ pode ser mais "rápido" em termos do tempo de execução do que usar floats?

Tags: c++, float, time

Tenho um programa desenvolvido em c++ no visual studio, que processa uma enorme quantidade de dados! Esse programa tanto pode utilizar dados do tipo float como double, sendo que essa especificação é feita da seguinte maneira:

```
typedef float/double real;
```

ou seja na declaração anterior, ou uso double ou float. Contudo deparei-me com um problema para o qual não encontro justificação. Nas configurações do meu projecto utilizando por defeito o floating point model: precise, o tempo que o programa demora a processar os dados no caso de floats é o dobro em relação a doubles. Se no floating point model utilizar a opção fast, usar floats ou doubles, demora sensivelmente o mesmo tempo, o que não me surpreende. Só não consigo compreender o porquê de no modo precise do floating point model, o tempo que demora ao utilizar floats é muito superior do que se usasse doubles (demora o dobro do tempo).
Obrigado!

Comment: Usando `double`, qual o "floating point model" usado? No modo "precise", o compilador precisa inserir código no entorno de qualquer operação de ponto flutuante para conformá-la com os padrões do IEEE para pontos flutuantes.

A única explicação plausível que eu vejo é que, com double, o código é gerado no modo "fast". Pode ser que o compilador só obedeça esta flag com o tipo "float", mas isso é especulação.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme Ivella comentou, o modo "precise" eh usado para quando vc precisa de mais precisao nos calculos com float.

O tempo extra parece estar na transmissao dos bits extras em cada uma das operacoes. O documento fala que nesse modo, usam-se 80 bits para cada float. Em um sistema 64 bits, isso significa o uso de registradores extra e/ou o dobro de ciclo do processador para armazenar esses numeros nas outras memorias.

Veja o documento da microsoft sobre o assunto:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e7s85ffb.aspx

original em ingles:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx